# Number of groups of order $2^n$ asymptotic formula?

Tags: group-theory, asymptotics

I was happily scrolling around the site with a couple integer sequences. And in particular looking at number of groups of a given cardinality as it has always been a question I found interesting. And I in particular looked at the following sequence http://oeis.org/A000679. Which is the number of groups of order $2^n$. And if you scroll down a bit you can find a neat asymptotic formula
$$a(n)=2^{(2/27)n^3+O(n^{8/3})}$$
I would like to read up more about it, I however have a few (2) problems:

1. Naively typing "groups of order $2^n$ into my search bar doesn't immediately lead me to what I want. So what should I search for? Or even better what can I read to find info about this.
2. I understand that this will obviously be related to group theory, but what other prerequisites are there? And how far in group theory should I have reached?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higman%E2%80%93Sims_asymptotic_formula

Comment: Maybe *groups of prime power order* will give better search results, or *number of 2-groups*.

Comment: Making any progress, Dev? Any reaction to the comments and the answer that have been posted?

Answer (score 2):

There is a book called "Enumeration of finite groups" by Blackburn, Neumann and Venkataraman. It gives the full proof as far as I remember.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I went to look at that book and it looks like a fun read